# DatatimePicker is displayed as soon as the composnat is opened in React Native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, expo

I hope you are doing well.
I have a problem with react native on Android.
In IOS, it works well but when i open a componant who includes a DataTimePicker in Android, it automatically shows me the DatatimePicker. Do you know what the problem is in my code ?

```
                 <View style={styles.dateContainer}>
                    <Text style={styles.customLabelDate}>
                        Date de naissance
                    </Text>
                    <DateTimePicker
                        testID="dateTimePicker"
                        value={stateForm.dateOfBirth}
                        mode="date"
                        is24Hour={true}
                        display="calendar"
                        onChange={(event, value) => {
                            dispatchStateForm({
                                type: UPDATE,
                                payload: { name: "dateOfBirth", value: value },
                            });
                        }}
                        style={styles.dateTime}
                        locale="fr-FR"
                        textColor="red"
                    />
                </View>
```

This is the result :

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually The problem kinda simple, just create the state that whether the datetimepicker should rendered or not. The guide said it also and recommend this:

src: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-community/datetimepicker#usage

[image]